# ASP.Net Web API SendAsync methods of DelegatingHandler called twice on POST request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have custom authorization handler in web api and when debugging web api i have found that SendAsync method of handler is called twice when post request is made. when get request is made method is executed one time only. I have also noted that request.Headers.Authorization is null first time and it contains value on second time. I have also noticed that when i remove authorization header form jquery ajax post request then method is called one time only. and fiddler also shows request as POST. but when i add header than first request is sent as OPTIONS /Product/Create HTTP/1.1 and second request as POST /Product/Create HTTP/1.1 in fiddler. anybody have idea why it is happening? and i am making cross domain request.

Comment: after spending half day on internet for problem finally got answer that when you add header in cross domain ajax request first Preflight request is made (OPTIONS) and then everything is ok then actual request done(POST). following linked helped me to understand cors request:

http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/12/ajax-cross-domain-requests-with-cors/

And finally find following article to handle Preflight request in delegating handler:

http://georgedurzi.com/implementing-cross-browser-cors-support-for-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 1):

It is called a CORS pre-flight request.  It is a security mechanism that allows a server the ability to grant a client the rights to perform a cross domain request.